# Is there a good find and replace tool for windows registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Registry Search & Replace Tool](https://superuser.com/questions/174942/registry-search-replace-tool)

Do you have recommandations for a good find and replace tool for windows registry?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention I am looking for a tool that will allow batch replacement of values in the registry (read hundreds of them).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The default built-in tool works great. You can access it by typing `regedit`.

Comment: Thank you for this info but I haven't been clear in my question that I was looking for a find and replace ALL occurences. Will update now...